# Is Laravel 5.4 compatible with PHP 7.3

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, compatibility

The company hosting my website (which was developed with Laravel 5.4 and PHP 5.6)  mandate a change to PHP 7.3, this has been done but I got an error; and I have to switch back to PHP 5.6 to maintain the site up and running.

I want to know if scripts developed in Laravel 5.4 are compatible with PHP 7.3

Comment: "but I got an error" - what error? I would be surprised if the core Laravel 5.4 packages weren't compatible with PHP 7.3, but third-party packages you may have installed may not be.

Comment: I recommend you to upgrade your Laravel version to at least `5.5` (the actual TLS version). Laravel `5.5` is still mantained and should be compatible with PHP `7.3`. Check [this guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade).

Comment: Use this script to check Laravel Compatible or not. https://github.com/GastonHeim/Laravel-Requirement-Checker . Save the check.php on your server and run. Choose the Laravel version on the server and it will say which requirements are not met.

Answer (score 3):

You can check PHP 7.3 compatibility of Laravel here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27052

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies must be causing the problem, you need to downgrade them running the `composer update` command on a terminal that has PHP version 5.6 in it, you can check the version with: `php -v`. Once  they are updated, you may upload your project again to the server that's running PHP 7.3